# Silent Installs of Programs in the answer file for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, images, disk-image, sysprep

I'm using Sysprep and Windows AIK to create a system image. I installed all the programs that won't need updating and wanted to create msi files for programs that usually update (like firefox or an antivirus) that can be installed automatically with my image. I couldn't find a tutorial that would explain how to do this. Any help or advice?

Comment: You need a tool like MDT or ConfigMgr to do this. MDT is free. But, you need configure it properly. This subject is really extensive and one answer wouldn't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to configure this manually, you can prepare scripts and run them during deployment with [the FirstLogonCommands setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff715886) in an answer file.

With that said, why configure the deployment manually when tools like the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)](http://technet.microsoft.com/windows/dn475741) or ConfigMgr, as Haplo suggested, are designed to perform these tasks?

Since you already have an image generated through the Windows AIK, I would suggest installing MDT and configuring a deployment share, then importing that image and the desired applications. To deploy the image and applications, you will need to create a deployment task sequence and prepare a method for booting.

In the deployment task sequence you can specify to either have specific applications installed or to have the user pick between available applications. You can also customize the deployment share or offline boot media to automate the deployment. You can even automate the deployment to the point where all you need to do is boot from the network, USB stick, or DVD and the deployment will run without user interaction.